# Incorrect Formula for nested if loops in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

Problem:

```
If K2 is blank AND N2 is blank = P2-I2
If K2 is blank = P2-L2
ELSE P2-O2
```

New to writing `if` statements with excel, but this is my formula and I am having a hard time catching my mistake:

`IF(AND(ISBLANK(K2), ISBLANK(N2)), P2-I2, IF(ISBLANK(N2), P2-L2, P2-O2))`

I am pasting that after the `"="` into excel. Any help would be great!

Comment: in the second test change **N2** to **K2**

Answer (score -1):

It's just the order in the formula because `K2` is in both conditions:

`=IF(ISBLANK(K2),P2-L2,IF(AND(ISBLANK(K2), ISBLANK(N2)),P2-I2,P2-O2))`

`=IF(K2="",P2-L2,IF(AND(K2="", N2=""),P2-I2,P2-O2))`

`=IF(LEN(K2)=0,P2-L2,IF(AND(LEN(K2)=0, LEN(N2)=0),P2-I2,P2-O2))`

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I still seem to be getting an error "#VALUE!"

Comment: I added to my answer another option. It could be a problem with `ISBLANK` function.

Comment: The second formula didn't work either. I feel it may be an issue with the ISBLANK function. Anyway to fix this?

Comment: You can test if the cell is blank with `=CODE(K2)`. If the result is `#VALUE!` the cell is blank if return some number it is the `ASCII number` for example: `32` for space. The other reason is the data type, if you see a number but excel is recognizing it as `text` it is imposible to do the operation.

Comment: So mine is returning #VALUE!. So it is blank. Any way to convert it to the data type that is needed in that case? I guess another option would be to upload this CSV to RStudio or Python.

Comment: you can select the whole column and with `Ctrl+1` you can access `Format cells...` there you can select the data type.

Comment: What if when you debug each `ISBLANK` code using **F9**? Are you getting `#VALUE!` error for each `ISBLANK` or just for some of them?

Comment: I added a third option to solve the problem. Let me know if it works!